# Put specific collection/array item on the last position in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a collection/array in rails, transformed to json it looks like this:

```
@collection = [{"order_number":"123","item":"Paper"},{"order_number":"567","item":"Ruler"},{"order_number":"344","item":"Pen"},{"order_number":"342","item":"Pencil"},{"order_number":"877","item":"Keyboard"}]
```

I would like to pick the item with the order_number "342" and put it at the last position of the collection, so the new collection looks like this:

```
@collection = [{"order_number":"123","item":"Paper"},{"order_number":"567","item":"Ruler"},{"order_number":"344","item":"Pen"},{"order_number":"877","item":"Keyboard"},{"order_number":"342","item":"Pencil"}]
```

In theory, it would look like this:

```
@collection.last = @collection[3]
```

but that is obviously not fancy ruby style nor would it re-sort the array as in my example.
Also I don't know the index of the item as it can change depending on what the user shops.

Comment: Do you always know it's index? or do you need to locate it? and do you want/need it sorted?

Comment: No I don't know its index, I would need to locate it. There are always different items in the collection depending on what the customer shops. So it would need to get sorted indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
@collection << @collection.delete_at[@collection.index{|x| x[:order_number] == "342"}]
```

This basically searches the index of element with `:order_number` 342 first, uses that index to delete it, and then store the deleted element at the end again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) method:

```
@collection = @collection.partition { |h| h['order_number'] != '342' }.flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split your collection on two (without 342 order and with 342 order), then just join them. It should looks like:

```
@collection = @collection.select {|e| e[:order_number] != '342' } + @collection.select {|e| e[:order_number] == '342' }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index of an item it boils down to

```
@collection << @collection.delete_at(3)
```

If you don't, you could try finding it using

```
@collection.find_index{ |el| el["order_number"] == "123" }
```

Comment: Sorry was not precise here, I don't know its index. I need to locate it first. And then sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can try this too:

```
> @collection.each_with_index{ |key,value| @collection.push(@collection.delete_at(value)) if key[:order_number] == "344" }
#=>[{:order_number=>"123", :item=>"Paper"}, {:order_number=>"567", :item=>"Ruler"}, {:order_number=>"342", :item=>"Pencil"}, {:order_number=>"877", :item=>"Keyboard"}, {:order_number=>"344", :item=>"Pen"}]
```